# creating exe for another computers in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, exe

I created a small windows form app in visual studio 2012 using c#, build it in release mode,the exe is not working on another computers

Comment: In what way does it not work?  There are plenty of things that could be wrong... can you at least tell us what errors you get when you try to run it on another computer?

Comment: simly unable tor run the .exe

Comment: So no error, no nothing, it just fails to run?

Comment: But it shows (possibly for only a second) in Task Manager? Have you put tracing in to see where it fails? Do you include all the references? Sounds like you are just X-Copying the exe.

Comment: did you put all references(assemblies) to .exe folder

Comment: Build a simple installer and it will work. There are other ways, but this is least painful

Answer (score 1):

With the default settings of a new C# project on VS2012, it will generate an EXE that cannot run on XP.  The default .NET Framework target for VS2012 is .NET 4.5, a version of .NET that is not available for XP.

But it does something else that's very important, it also marks the target Windows version in the EXE header.  This field has been set to version 4.00, the version number of Windows NT and Windows 95 for as long as .NET has been around.  Even though it doesn't actually run on those old Windows versions.

New with the .NET 4.5 compilers, it will now set the target version to 6.00, the Vista version.  This is a rather important step ahead, running a program that's marked for 4.00 on a newer version turns on a couple of app-compat shims.  An important one that's caused plenty of trouble is the shim for programs that don't know about Aero, in particularly its fat window borders.  Your program is lied to by Windows when you ask for the window size.  You'll get a faked size, smaller by 6 pixels.

The side-effect of this change is that your program will instantly fail on XP, even before you get to find out that the required .NET version isn't installed.  Windows will immediately reject the EXE.

Change the .NET Framework target setting of your project to 4.0 or less to create a program that will run on XP.

Answer (score 0):

Install all dependencies(like .net) and other files if required on the other computer

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a EXE from 'Visual Studio setup project' because the bin folder 'exe' should contain only primary output. But you need to install the require dependencies to install and use the other systems.

How to create an EXE?
http://balanagaraj.wordpress.com/2007/05/29/create-exe-or-setup-file-in-net-windows-application/